# Create 3x3 ImagesButtons with tablelayout with defined sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Im having issues trying to create a layout like the following one:

[Desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxgjl.png)

So far, i have this:

[What i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy5Yw.png)

I am using tablelayout and what i wish is 3x3 squares (imagebuttons), perfect squares, each button will have a image that should be the exact size of the square.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:text="Row 2 column 1"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Row 2 column 2"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:text="Row 2 column 3"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 1"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:text="Row 2 column 2"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:text="Row 2 column 3"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/btn1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView08" android:text="Row 2 column 2"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView09" android:text="Row 2 column 3"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

        </TableRow>

        <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->


    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TableRow should contain **WeightSum = 3** (columns),
then add 3 LinearLayout ( remember to set **android:layout_weight="1"**) which contains imageView with TextView

```
<TableRow
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <ImageButton....../>

        <TextView ...../>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <ImageButton....../>

        <TextView ...../>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp">

        <ImageButton....../>

        <TextView ...../>
    </LinearLayout>


</TableRow>
```

Comment: But those are not imagebuttons

Comment: You may put imagebuttons instead of